# Measuring Thermal Conductivity Of a material

Tags: solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

I need to measure the thermal conductivity of a solid material which contains polyurethane. I know that the conductivity could be measured experimentally by setting up an experiment, and it could also be measured using measurement devices. But I want to use a reliable device to make the process repeatable ,fast, and reliable. Would you recommend buying and using a lab device for this purpose?

Could you give me recommendation about what kind of thermal conductivity measurement device to use for this purpose? Anyone who has some experience on these fields, I would appreciate any guidance. There are lots of devices, some are expensive and some are cheap. Is there any device that you would recommend that is reliable and worth investing on?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether you should buy one for yourself or not is mostly a business decision - how often do you need to make the measurements, are they important to qualifying your material, and is there an available 3rd party testing laboratory are key there. But without a solid business case to buy one, worrying about just which one to buy is ill defined. Your need will define which one will meet it.